# Convolutional neural network filter selection

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am having trouble capturing edges of a input image. I want to capture edges at an angle(say 45 degrees) using 5x5 filter. What would be my 5x5 matrix?

Comment: You are manually looking for a matrix you mean? Usually, the filters are found via training of a CNN.

Comment: Please share some more insights such as your code snippet or function or methods. Include you code here and share what error you are getting and where exactly you are stucked? Better to add which IDE, language and framework you are using in the question description.